# Database choice for large dataset

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I am currently working on a project (for fun) that uses data about different areas using geolocation coordinates.

Which database system would be easiest / most powerful, for querying data based on this. I have thought about grouping location information for areas into a separate table in a MySQL database. Would this lead to performance issues or is there a better DBMS to use for grouping data in this way?

I would like to use a php back end but wouldn't mind also learning a new language if really required.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Obviously the only way to go is full enterprise oracle for a mere $100k... or just go with mysql for free and scale up if you feel you need better performance.

Comment: What is the size of data you are dealing with?

Comment: MySQL because its for fun and you don't want to spend a fortune.

Comment: SQL Server supports geospatial datatypes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx

Comment: MySQL or Postgresql are good options and if you want to use geo-locations and want to perform earth distance calculations then Postgresql is best option

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with MySQL then that would be the easiest.  There are many different ones that you can try.  MongoDB is popular, postgresql is popular as well.  There are many MySQL databases that have millions of rows.  You have to make sure your tables are structured right with good relations.  You also need to utilize views and make sure your table types are right.  Some lock the whole table and others just a row.  Really, I think any database will work well for what you want.

don't forget indexes.